# How to change the date of any format like 20080408 or 2008/04/08 or 08/04/2008

Tags: r, date

Please help as I have a csv file of large database with date column having various format of dates like `20080408` or `2008/04/08` or `08/04/2008`.How do  i change these format to one format of `dd/mm/yyyy`.In R Programing

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with failure tests via `lubridate` `dmy` and `mdy` conversions as well (hence the `suppressWarnings()` calls. I don't think you're going to be able to ensure proper handling of things like `"08/04/2008"` if `08` is supposed to be the "day" component, tho, given that the functions can't read minds.

```
library(lubridate)

dat <- c("20080408", "2008/04/08", "08/04/2008")

dat.1 <- unlist(lapply(dat, function(x) {

  suppressWarnings(res <- mdy(x))
  if (is.na(res)) { suppressWarnings(res <- ymd(x)) }
  return(as.character(res))

}))

dat.1
## [1] "2008-04-08" "2008-04-08" "2008-08-04"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for your `data.frame`. You may need to convert your date column to the class `as.character` in order that the string split function `strsplit` works correctly. After tha, the loop simply evaluates how many characters are in the string before the first "/" character, and adjusts the formatting accordingly.

#### Example:

```
df <- data.frame(DATE=as.character(c("20080408", "2008/04/08", "08/04/2008")), DATE2=as.Date(NA))
df$DATE=as.character(df$DATE)
  
for(i in seq(df$DATE)){
    sp <- unlist(strsplit(df$DATE[i], "/"))
    if(nchar(sp[1]) == 8){
        df$DATE2[i] <- as.Date(df$DATE[i], format="%Y%m%d")
    }   
    if(nchar(sp[1]) == 4){
        df$DATE2[i] <- as.Date(df$DATE[i], format="%Y/%m/%d")
    }
    if(nchar(sp[1]) == 2){
        df$DATE2[i] <- as.Date(df$DATE[i], format="%d/%m/%Y")
    }
}
```

#### Result:

```
df
#        DATE      DATE2
#1   20080408 2008-04-08
#2 2008/04/08 2008-04-08
#3 08/04/2008 2008-04-08
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish I  need some more help as I m new to R.I  want to check a data set with how many different format of dates are the there in dataset of 50000 then I wish to apply a sinngle date format to it.How do I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can read them as `character` values and convert them using `as.Date`.

```
x1 <- '20080408'     ## class character (string)
x2 <- '2008/04/08'
x1.dt <- as.Date(x1, format='%Y%m%d')
x2.dt <- as.Date(x2, format='%Y/%m/%d')   ## different format
print(c(x1, x2), format='%d/%m/%Y')       ## you can return Date objects in any format you want
```

Check out `?strftime` for all the formatting options.